# Stopping an infinite loop Runnable run from ThreadPool

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

I have a `Runnable` implementing class which will be run from a `Executors.newFixedThreadPool`
Inside the `Runnable`, I have an infinite-loop running which listens on an UDP Port for incoming data.

I want to gracefully end the `Runnable` in order to close said UDP Ports.

How can I achieve this?
When extending `Thread` directly, I have access to interrupt() and isInterupted() etc. on which I can base my infinite loop.

In the `Runnable` implementing class however, I want to to do something like

```
@Override
public void run() {
    while (active) {

    }
}
```

and have

```
private boolean active = true;
```

How can I set active = false when the ThreadPool is terminated?

Comment: You have only this kind of Runnable on your thread pool?

Comment: yes. what other kinds of RUnnable are there?

Comment: lol! Sry, my english is very poor.. anyway, i want to know if all objects you submit to your pool is the same class. Or implement a common interface (other than Runnable).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can access the interrupt flag of the current thread using the static method  [`Thread.interrupted()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupted%28%29), e.g. instead of your `active` flag use:

```
public void run() {
    try {
        // open your ports
        while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
            // do stuff
        }
    } finally {
        // close your ports in finally-block
        // so they get closed even on exceptions
    }
}
```

And when you want to shutdown your `ExecutorService`, call [`shutdownNow()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdownNow%28%29) on it. This will `interrupt()` any running worker threads and have your `Runnable` break out of its loop.

Answer (score 2):

if you get a Future when you submit the task you can `cancel(boolean)` the future, if you pass true the thread the task is running on will be interrupted

```
@Override
public void run() {
    try{
        while (!Thread.interrupted()) {


             if(Thread.interrupted())return;//to quit from the middle of the loop
        }
    }finally{
        //cleanup
    }
}
```

note that you'll have to reset the interrupted flag with `Thread.currentThread().interrupt();` each time you get a thrown InterruptedException

Answer (score 1):

you can use this

```
while (!executor.isShutdown) {
//do your job
}
```

or use an `AtomicBoolean` in the while loop. (preferable over `volatile`)

This flag can be set if you want to stop processing manually, from some method like `stopProcessing()`

Comment: so I would need to keep a reference to the calling executor.
and what's happening when I shutdown the executor? does it wait for the termination of all threads within? if not, the executor might terminate and the (!executor.isShutdown) will not be reached?

Comment: Yes, you need a reference. If you use `executor.shutdown` the javadoc says that : "Initiates an orderly shutdown in which previously submitted tasks are executed, but no new tasks will be accepted." Internally this interrupts all the idle threads. So I guess this waits for the termination of all the threads within.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to not use 'Runnable', rather override 'FutureTask' and implement it's 'done' and 'cancel' (if necessary) methods - where you can make all the necessary clean up operations.

EDIT:

forgot `cancel' method.